# Как работать с клон-элементом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Я создал клон-элемент, теперь не знаю как сделать так, чтобы всё что я пишу изначальному элементу применялось также и к клону.

Comment: Смотря что "пишешь"... Желательно сделать хоть какой-то минимальный тестовый пример - на нем можно будет что-то показать.

Comment: А вы сначала примените все пропорции к оригинальному элементу, а потом уже создавайте клон :)